# How to use private packages in Azure Pipelines During CI/CD builds

Tags: flutter, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using Azure CI/CD pipelines for Flutter build. In my Pubspec yaml file, I have dependencies that are private to my project and the code is hosted in same azure devops project but in different repository. During Build (i.e. Flutter Packages get) it gives me error saying Authentication failed?. I tried with PAT token where in prior to flutter build task i used git command to set that token, but it didn't solve the issue. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am open to being shown a better way but these are the steps I took to solve this issue a little while ago.

Assuming you are referencing the package in your pubspec.yaml using git over ssh on azure devops like:

```yaml
  repo_name:
    git:
      ref: 'tag or other identifier'
      url: you@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/you/project/repo_name
```

- Generate a new ssh key pair on your machine.
- Upload the private key to the library secure files section on azure devops.
- Add the install ssh key task to your azure pipelines build, using the key pair generated in the previous steps and referencing the private key uploaded to the secure files library. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops)
- Upload the public key to your list of public keys. (This step I'm not 100% sure is necessary but I did it initially and things have worked so I haven't changed removed it)

So in my azure-pipelines.yaml the install ssh key step looks kinda like this where id_rsa is the name of the private key in my secure files.

```yaml
          - task: InstallSSHKey@0
            inputs:
              knownHostsEntry: 'vs-ssh.visualstudio.com, ...etc'
              sshPublicKey: 'ssh-rsa ...etc'
              sshKeySecureFile: id_rsa
```

Comment: How did you get the known hosts value?

Comment: I tried this step, but I was having issue with authentication. Basically I have a project having two repos. 1st repo is having my main source code of application and second repo has plugin code private to my application. So in my pubspec yaml file I have the ssh url of the repository plugin which I wanted to refer. But during pipeline build it is saying as authentication failed. I created a ssh- key pair in my local machine uploaded the public key and private key to secure variables.

Comment: To get the known hosts value, I just cleared the known hosts file from my ~/.ssh/known_hosts file. then interacted with the repos via git remote update, which populated my known_hosts file with just the entries for azure devops, and used that.

Comment: I have a similar setup to the one you described, where it is one project where the main app references another repo in the project as plugin code.
Do you mind sharing a bit more about what your build pipeline and pubspec.yaml looks like? With any sensitive information removed of course.

Comment: @GssAditya Late to the party, but did you manage to solve issue with "But during pipeline build it is saying as authentication failed. " Hitting same issue right now.

Comment: I actually managed to get a PAT (Personal Access token) from the Azure repository and added the PAT token in my package.json or code folder and it worked as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

A private feed is created with permissions such that only you have access.

The build agent run with user(build service account), give to this user permissions in the feed. From Feed settings->Permissions, assign your build service account  owner permission.

Also verify the  token is working, make sure you have selected sufficient [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes) for this token to authorize for your specific tasks.

Besides try adding a variable `system.debug` with a value of true you’ll get more information in the failure. That might help pinpoint the problem.